# How do I remove a value from Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

My session is not getting destroyed. This is how I set it up in Login.aspx.cs:

```
Session["User"] = UserName.Text; // Set the session called User.
```

Link on the MasterPage:

```
<a href="Login.aspx" id="loginButton"><img src="images/login.png"><span runat="server" id="authspan">Login</span></a>
```

The text in the link changes depending on whether the user has session or not:

```
    if (Session["User"] != null)
    {
        authspan.InnerHtml = "Logout";
    }
    else
    {
        authspan.InnerHtml = "Login";
    }
```

This link redirects to Login.aspx file in which on PageLoad I tell the code to close the session. In theory, this should work, right?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["User"] != null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx"); // Redirect user.
        Session["User"] = null; 
        Session.Remove("User"); 
    }
    else 
    {
        // run code that logs the user in, and sets up the session.
    }

}
```

How can I end it for the logged in user correctly?

Comment: You're not trying to destroy the session, just remove a value from it, correct?

Comment: Correct, apologies on incorrect wording. Still learning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must first clear session and then redirect.

```
    Session["User"] = null; 
    Session.Remove("User"); 
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx"); // Redirect user.
```

Also note that, it is safer to remove session id on client side too:

```
    var sessionCookie = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId");
    sessionCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(sessionCookie);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
Session.Clear();
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the value from session in different ways

```
//Set the session variable
Session["User"]=Value;
//Destroy the session variable
Session.Remove("User");
Session["User"]=null;
```

// Abandon will destroy the session completely, meaning that you need to    begin a new session before you can store any more values in the session for that user
    Session.Abandon();
   //Clearing the session will not unset the session, it still exists with the same ID for the user but with the values simply cleared.
    Session.Clear();

Answer (score 0):

Call `Session.Abandon();` (and I must write at least 30 chars)